# How to send a item name or titel into a form input field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created a contact form using PHP and now I want to add to an Item a button, for example, ADD or + that when I push it, the Item name will be added inside the form item name field automatically and I want to be able to add more than 1 inside that field, after each item would be like a 
 or a , .

How can I do this?

Comment: Adding code in your question can help better to understand the problem.

Comment: I don't have a code, I wanted some pointers in how to start making it

Answer (score 1):

This is the rough approach; Onclick of button , modify the value of input box; scale it up to your needs

```js
let valuesToAdd = {
 "input" : "hello world",
 "input1" : "hi there",
 "input2" : "how are you",
 "input3" : "Nice to see you",
 "input4" : "hola mi hermano"
}

document.getElementById("add").onclick = addValue;

function addValue() {
  let keys = Object.keys(valuesToAdd);
  for(i=0;i<keys.length;i++) {  
     document.getElementById(keys[i]).value = valuesToAdd[keys[i]]
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input" placeholder = "helloworld"/>
<input type="text" id="input1" placeholder = "helloworld"/>
<input type="text" id="input2" placeholder = "helloworld"/>
<input type="text" id="input3" placeholder = "helloworld"/>
<input type="text" id="input4" placeholder = "helloworld"/>
<button id="add">
add text to input
</button>
```

Comment: Yea its a good approach but I need to add multiple values to it, If I have let's say 10 items and I want to add all 10

Comment: I have changed my approach for 5 inputs; scale it up to your need;

Comment: It's a good approach, I have to think it first on how my end result has to be since I'm sending my data with PHP so I need to see how the receiving mail will look

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="wrap">
    <button>Add value</button>
    <input name="myinputvalue[]" value="" />
</div>


$("button").on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var elem = $(this).parent().find('input[name=myValue\\[\\]]');

    elem.val( elem.val() + 'add Me' );
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/D97bV/107/